# EasyUI Treegrid - insert method does not update children collection

Tags: jquery, treegrid, jquery-easyui

I am using [jQuery EasyUI treegrid](http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=TreeGrid&theme=default&dir=ltr&pitem=) on a project.

I have a tree loaded with some initial data. Afterwards, I need to insert new rows on the tree when user clicks "Add" button. The add click handler has this code and it is working somewhat as expected:

```
var row = $treeGrid.treegrid('getSelected');

if (row) {
    var obj = {
        id: "x" + ++maxId,
        code: "x" + maxId,
        amount: 2
    };
    $treeGrid.treegrid('insert', {
            after: row.id,
            data: obj
        });

    $("#txtResult").text("Added a new row: " + obj.id);
}
```

However afterwards when I check the children of the row (where a new child was added), it does not include the newly added row.

I have setup a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kashiif/UKept/) to demonstrate the issue. To reproduce it:

1. Select a row at 2nd level and click Add child. A new row would be added as per the code above. A "row added" message is displayed below the buttons.
2. Select the parent and click "Show Children" button. The children count of the selected row is shown below the buttons.

After inserting row, I have also tried "acceptChanges" of treegrid but it still does not solve the problem.

**UPDATE**: As per @saigitha-vijay answer, it looks like using append method correctly updates the underlying model ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4yMy/2/)) however it always adds the new row as last child. Is there anyway to add new row at a particular position?

Answer (score 0):

Instead on 'insert' use the 'append'. In this method, u can pass the parent id too.

example,

```
$('#tt').treegrid('append',{
parent: node.id,  // the node has a 'id' value that defined through 'idField' property
data: [{
    id: '073',
    name: 'name73'
}]
});
```

i modified your code as,(its working)

```
 var obj = [{
            id: "x" + ++maxId,
            code: "x" + maxId,
            amount: 2
        }];

        $treeGrid.treegrid('append', {
            parent: row.id,
            data: obj
        });
```

Comment: Here is the fiddle that uses add and works: http://jsfiddle.net/n4yMy/2/
However What about inserting the rows?

Comment: You can have two buttons as "add" and "insert after"... in add button event use 'append' method and in "insert after" use 'insert' method.